# What is density matrix in QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, density-operator

In quantum mechanics exist fundamental object [Density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix). (See for introduction last chapter in  [Principles of Quantum Mechanics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/PQM.html) by David Skinner). Density matrix nesesary to describe systems
even when we’re not sure which state they’re in. 
I wanna to understand about generalisation of this object to QFT.

What is density matrix in QFT?

What is differences between density matrix in QFT and QM?

What is meaning of non-diagonal elements of density matrix?

Comment: Please develop a bit more the topic.

Comment: Any QFT is QM (duh!). Thus, the density matrix is given by the exact same expression, and it has the exact same physical interpretation. The Hilbert space is much wilder so it may be more difficult to define things in a mathematically precise way, but physically it is very much the same thing. QFT is not more general than old-school QM -- more like the other way around: QFT is a proper subset of QM.

Comment: I disagree. In QFT you have not fixed number of particles. They can be created and destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Is this dencity matrix powerful? What kind of information can one extract using such matrix?

Comment: @Nikita One popular application of density matrices in QFT is the computation of entanglement entropies from reduced density matrices. See for example this review article, where you can find some formal expressions for computing reduced density matrices in QFTs: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2562